# sql запрос с множеством WHERE

Tags: sql

```
DB::select("SELECT products.id FROM products, additional_options, option_values, options
            WHERE ((option_values.url = 'no' AND options.url = 'relay_output')
            AND (option_values.url = '2ТРМ1' AND options.url = 'series'))
            AND (option_values.option_id = options.id)
            AND (option_values.id = additional_options.option_value_id)
            AND (products.id = additional_options.product_id)");
```

Данный запрос выдает пустой массив, хотя должен выдать несколько айдишников товаров. Подскажите, где может быть ошибка

Comment: по все видимости условия в двойных скобках должны выглядеть не так

((option_values.url = 'no' AND options.url = 'relay_output')
            AND (option_values.url = '2ТРМ1' AND options.url = 'series'))

а вот так

((option_values.url = 'no' AND options.url = 'relay_output')
            OR (option_values.url = '2ТРМ1' AND options.url = 'series'))

Comment: @sterx вы предлагаете использовать OR, а мне надо чтобы соответствовало и то и другое

Comment: но вы понимаете что поля option_values.url и options.url могут в одной записи БД содержать только одно значение. а ваш первоначальный запрос предполагает два значение в одном поле...

Comment: @sterx эм, а как мне тогда быть? мне нужно получить ид товаров зная только характеристики, а их может быть выбрано много

Comment: очевидно что множественные возможные значения для поля с одним значением должны быть либо перечислены через OR либо используя конструкцию - field IN (value1,value2......valueN)

Comment: @sterx можно попросить вас показать на моем примере? я уже целый день бьюсь пытаюсь понять =(

Comment: возможный вариант я написал в первом комментарии. без данных перед глазами трудно понять как там у вас все устроено

Comment: Показанный запрос править бесполезно - он в принципе не "доводится до ума". Необходимо работать с данными на двух уровнях группировки (детально и с группировкой по продукту), а это как минимум две копии исходной таблицы (формально либо оконные функции, но не в данном случае).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Типовая задача - хранение атрибутов объекта в EAV-таблице и фильтр по набору параметров и значений.

Выборка по множественному фильтру выполняется следующим образом - из таблицы атрибутов выбираются пары атрибут-значение, соответствующие условию, результат группируется по объекту, подсчитывается количество соответствий, и отбираются объекты, для которых количество соответствий равно количеству пар в фильтре.

Схематично:

```
CREATE TABLE eav_values (object_id, parameter, value);

SELECT object_id
FROM eav_values 
WHERE (parameter, value) IN (  ('parameter_1', 'value_1'),
                               ('parameter_2', 'value_2'),
                               -- .....................
                               ('parameter_N', 'value_N')
                             )
GROUP BY object_id
HAVING COUNT(/* DISTINCT */ parameter, value) = N
```

В случае, если структура гарантирует уникальность пары `(parameter-value)`, достаточно `HAVING COUNT(*) = N`.

Далее, если необходимо, эта выборка используется как подзапрос для отбора записей из таблицы объектов и/или отдельных пар `(parameter-value)` из таблицы параметров.

В более сложных случаях (например, диапазонные условия, условия с весовыми коэффициентами и пр.) вместо прямого отбора в секции `WHERE` или в дополнение к нему используется накопление условных сумм в секции `HAVING`.